# bash scripting how to filter the most counted first line var

Tags: bash

How to filter the most counted first line var in all the files under directory (where other directories should also be checked)?
I want to find all the lines in my files (I want all the files in lots of folders under `pwd`) first variable where this first var display the most times

I am trying to use `awk` like this:

```
awk -f : { print $1} FILENAME
```

EDIT:
I will explain the purpose:
I have a server and i want to filter his logs cause I have a certain IP which repeat every day 100 times the first var in line is the ip 
I want the find what is the ip which repeats problem : i have two servers therefore checking this will not be effiant by checking one log for 100 times  I hope that this script will help me find out what is the IP that repeats ...

Comment: `awk -f :` tries to read the script from a file named `:` (and would then process `{`, `print`, `$1}` and FILENAME as file names).  You may have meant `awk -F : '{print $1}' FILENAME`.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Could you elaborate with an example input and desired output?

Comment: You're going to need to expand on what you are after.  It sounds a bit as if you are after the most commonly occurring prefix for the lines in the files under your current directory, where the prefix is the part of the line up to the first colon (if there is a colon at all - otherwise, the whole line).

Answer (score 2):

You should rewrite your question to make it clearer. I understood that you want to know which first lines are most common across a set of files. For that, I'd use this:

```
head -qn 1 * | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

`head` prints the first line for every file in the current directory. `-q` causes it not to print the name of the file too; -n lets you specify the amount of lines).

`sort` groups them in sorted order.

`uniq -c` counts the occurrences, that is the amount of repeated lines in each block after the previous sort.

`sort -r` orders them with the most popular coming first. `-r` means reverse; by default it sorts in ascending order.

Comment: can you explain what each parameter does please

Comment: I tried to make it clearer, let me know if something's missing.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, if this helps. Question is not so clear.

Try if something like this can help.

```
find . -type f -name "*.*" -exec head -1 {} \; 2>/dev/null | awk -F':' 'BEGIN {max=0;}{if($2>max){max=$2;}}END{print max;}'
```

find - tries to find all the files from the current directory till end (`type f`) with any name and extension (`*.*`) and gets the first line of each of those files.

awk - sets the field seperator as : (`-F:`) and before processing the first line `BEGIN` sets the max to 0. 
gets the second field after : `($2)` checks if `$2 > current_max_value`. If it is, then it sets the current field as the new max value.
At the end of processing all the lines(first lines from all the files under current directory) `END` prints the max value.